# Including squared predictors in model matrix

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(2, 3, 4)
z <- c(3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

model.matrix(x ~ .^4, df)
```

This gives me a model matrix with predictors $y, z$, and $y:z$. However, I also want y^2 and z^2, and want to use a solution that uses "$.$", since I have lots of other predictors beyond $y$ and $z$. What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3)
> y <- c(2, 3, 4)
> z <- c(3, 4, 5)
> df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
> 
> #Assuming that your 1st column is the response variable, then I excluded it to have
> #just the independent variables as a new data.frame called df.2
> df.2=df[,-1]
> model.matrix(x ~ .^4+I(df.2^2), df)
  (Intercept) y z I(df.2^2)y I(df.2^2)z y:z
1           1 2 3          4          9   6
2           1 3 4          9         16  12
3           1 4 5         16         25  20
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3 3 4
```